# How to I construct this type of SQL statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with a lastaccess date in a unix format.  I would like to query all the records in the table where the lastaccess date is greater than 180 days.

This is my current query

```
SELECT  id, auth, username, IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess))>=180,'Y','N') As NotAccessedIn6Months
FROM  mdl_user 
WHERE auth = 'manual'
```

I need to be able to use the NotAccessedIn6Months result to filter the resultset, like

```
SELECT  id, auth, username, IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess))>=180,'Y','N') As NotAccessedIn6Months
FROM  mdl_user 
WHERE auth = 'manual' AND NotAccessedIn6Months = 'Y'
```

but the latter format is illegal.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact error message that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: either use HAVING instead of WHERE, like this:

```
SELECT id, auth, username, 
       IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess))>=180,'Y','N') As NotAccessedIn6Months
  FROM mdl_user 
 WHERE auth = 'manual' 
HAVING NotAccessedIn6Months = 'Y'
```

... or just move this condition into WHERE (as you won't show 'N' values at all in this particular query), like that:

```
SELECT id, auth, username 
  FROM mdl_user 
 WHERE auth = 'manual' 
   AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess)) >= 180
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you combine it in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT  id, auth, username
FROM  mdl_user 
WHERE auth = 'manual' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess))>=180
```

Answer (score 1):

[HAVING specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate function used in SELECT statement.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)

```
SELECT  id,
        auth,
        username,
        IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(lastaccess))>=180,'Y','N')
            As NotAccessedIn6Months
FROM  mdl_user 
WHERE auth = 'manual'
HAVING NotAccessedIn6Months = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the calculated value alias in the WHERE but it is possible in HAVING clause.
However, this will have a performance impact since HAVING won't filter at query time but on the full resultset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id, auth, username
FROM  mdl_user 
WHERE auth = 'manual' AND lastaccess < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - interval 180 DAY)
```

You can also use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`